# Setting Email Body from variables pulled off SCORM

Tags: javascript, email, scorm

I have a course that is housed on an LMS where users input text. I want them to be able to either print or email themselves their notes. I have a piece of javascript within the course that opens a new html window which uses html, css and js. to format the page and call the variables from the course.

I successfully set up the print button, BUT when I tried to re-write the script for the email option. It doesn't work, at all. I'm not sure what I missed/am doing wrong. I'll post the working javascript for the print button and the nonworking script.

```
    /This will get the current date for the user
var d = new Date(),curr_date = d.getDate(),curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1,curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var player = opener?opener.GetPlayer():{} ;
/* ------------------ this is ONLY for debugging ----------- */
if (!player.GetVar) player={
    GetVar : function(idx) {
        return {printTitle:"Please access this workbook from within the module", printUserName:"Unknown"}[idx]
    }
}
/* ------------------ the above is ONLY for debugging ----------- */
$(function() {
  if (window.print) {
    $("#print").text("Print").on("click",function() { window.focus(); window.print() })
    $("#printDiv").show();
  }
  var title = player.GetVar("printTitle"), userName = player.GetVar("printUserName");
  $("#title").html(title);
  $("#userName").html(userName);
  $("#date").html(curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year);
  var numberOfAnswers = $(".answer").length;
  for (var i=1;i<=numberOfAnswers;i++) {
    var $content = $("#answer"+i);
    var q = player.GetVar("Q"+i);
    q=q?q.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>"):"No response provided."
    // window.console && console.log(q);
    $content.append("<p>"+(q)+"</p>");
  }
});
```

The broken code

```
     $(function(){
  if (window.email) {
    $(".SendEmail").text("Email").click(function(event) 
      Var email="emailaddress";
      var subject="Module 5 Reflections";
      var email body="content";
      var attach= "path";
      document.location= "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailbody+"?attach=
    });
    ]);
  }
 var useremail= player.GetVar("emailaddress");
  $("#title").html(title);
  $("#emailaddress").html(emailaddress);
  $("#date").html(curr_month + "-" + curr_date + "-" + curr_year);
  var numberOfAnswers = $(".answer").length;
  for (var i=1;i<=numberOfAnswers;i++) {
    var $content = $("#answer"+i);
    var q = player.GetVar("Q"+i);
    q=q?q.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>"):"No response provided."
    // window.console && console.log(q);
    $content.append("<p>"+(q)+"</p>");
  }
});
```

Comment: will the course be run in a classroom environment that you have control of the software on? what happens if there is no email client installed? Not sure if you have ability to send mail from the server but that may be a better option

Comment: "t doesn't work, at all." -- Please be more specific about what isn't working as you expect

Comment: Not sure that it is the cause or a copy+paste error, but `var email body=...` has a space in it that I don't think you intend.

Comment: As @EatPeanutButter suggested, we need more information. What does the console in the developer tools contain?